# Docker login private repository doesnt work but can wget login url

Tags: docker, authentication, repository, harbor

I've been stuck on this for ages today.

> [almalinux@drone-ci ~]$ wget https://*redacted*/v2/
> --2022-10-18 15:19:15--  https://*redacted*/v2/
> Resolving *redacted* (*redacted*)... *redacted*
> Connecting to *redacted* (*redacted*)|*redacted*|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
> Username/Password Authentication Failed.

So I can establish the server can connect to the server but then when I do docker login *redacted* this happens.

> sudo docker login *redacted*
> Username: dfsf
> Password:
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://*redacted*/v2/": Get "https://*redacted*:*redacted*:443/service/token?account=dfsf&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=harbor-registry": dial tcp: lookup *redacted*:*redacted*: no such host

No such host? whats going on it's clearly resolved the IP address.

This is just a basic docker installation. The private repository is harbor installed using letsencrypt certificates.